# Модульное программирование

Tags: проектирование, модули, code-style

Все мы в общих чертах знаем, что такое модульность - это разделение ответственности. Проблема заключается в том, что во многих случаях между модулями возникают зависимости. И не просто однонаправленные зависимости, а взаимные зависимости.

Например, модуль **A** предоставляет ряд функций, некоторые из которых используются в модуле **B**, а модуль **B** в свою очередь предоставляет ряд функций, некоторые из которых используются в модуле **A**.

С ростом числа проектов, в которых я участвовал, растет и количество вопросов.

Например, вот ситуация (казалось бы, простая), над которой я думаю уже вторую неделю, и никак не могу прийти к решению, которое меня бы полностью устроило:

Есть игра, подобная танкам, в которые многие из нас играли на *денди*. В этой игре есть три модуля, которые обладают неприятными взаимозависимостями - **игрок**, **враги** и **пули**.

Каждый модуль предоставляет функции контроля, перемещения и отрисовки. И еще некоторые возможности. Неприятность заключается в том, что модуль **пули** в функции обработки попаданий должен использовать модули **игрок** и **враги**, чтобы иметь доступ к положению, прочности и прочим параметрам этих сущностей.

И при этом, модули **игрок** и **враги** так же используют модуль **пули**, чтобы иметь доступ к функции **bullet_new()**, которая создает новую пулю, процесс создания которой контролируется в функциях управления игроком и врагами.

И это один из самых очевидных и простых случаев взаимных зависимостей. Я встречал куда более сложные, в виде сложных графов, некоторые узлы которого имеют десятки связей. И это в языках без **ООП**! То, что я видел в промышленном **ООП** коде, вообще не поддается какому-либо анализу. Там все происходит везде. Поэтому, я бы хотел разобраться в подходах организации модульности на примерах процедурного подхода.

Вопросы заключаются вот в чем:

1) Существуют ли вообще способы делать *любые* модули без взаимных зависимостей?

2) Что делать, если все же взаимные зависимости возникли?

3) Есть ли литература по организации модульности в процедурных языках?

Comment: Думаю, не стоит привязывать вопрос к конкретному языку. Данная проблема актуальна в принципе ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: С Вашего позволения поменяю тэги на более сопутствующие вопросу) А сам вопрос очень интересен. Хотелось бы услышать мнение бывалых разработчиков по данной проблеме

Comment: В паскале/делфи нельзя делать циклические ссылки между модулями. Тем не менее, программы на паскале и делфи пишутся без проблем.

Comment: В моем примере про взаимные зависимости от взаимных зависимостей можно избавиться, но тогда организация модулей будет мягко говоря странной. Например, модули **игрок**, **враги** и **пули** будут предоставлять лишь сами сущности, а обрабатываться эти сущности будут в модулях **рисовать**, **контролировать**, **двигаться** и пр.
Но этот случай очень прост, далеко не всегда можно сделать что-то подобное.

Comment: Ваша организация модулей будет "мягко говоря странной", потому что ваш пример сам по себе "мягко говоря странный". Почему игрок и враг - разные сущности? Вам нужны сущности `Танк` и `Пуля`, у `Танк`а будет метод `новаяПуля` и метод `выстрелить(Пуля пуля, Танк другойТанк)`.

Comment: Фаулера почитайте. И Джошуа Кериевски «Рефакторинг с использованием шаблонов».

Comment: Я хочу разобраться в модульности в процедурных языках, о существовании ООП и паттернов я знаю, там проблемы еще более запутанные и сложные.

Comment: @Dmitry, окей, опустим тот факт, что танк - это лишь общая часть сущностей врага и игрока. Сами сущности врага и игрока отличаются очень существенно, как и набор параметров, правил и пр. Хорошо, давайте рассмотрим ваш пример. Танк имеет метод **выстрелить**, который зовет действие из модуля **пули**. В модуле **пули** должен быть контроль попаданий в танки и стены. Следовательно, модуль пуль должен иметь доступ к карте, врагам и игроку. Проблема взаимозависимости осталась. ООП с наследованием и полиморфизмом проблему не решает, а лишь усугубляет для понимания.

Comment: Модульность не всегда союзник, особенно когда нужны оптимизации производительности :(

Comment: @Максим Нет, у пули ничего такого нет, а вот у танка есть приватное свойство `ИгроваяМеханика`, которое является классом, реализующим игровую механику. Танк вызывает метод `игроваяМеханика.посчитатьПопадание(self, пуля, цель)`, а уже класс игровой механики определяет, попал танк, или промазал, и что там еще.

Comment: Правда, почитайте Фаулера и Кириевски. У них 100500 таких примеров разобрано.

Comment: @Dmitry, как же **.просчитатьПопадание()** получит информацию о врагах, стенах и пр.? Только через использование соответствующих модулей. К тому же предполагается, что пули находятся в пуле пуль, а следовательно просчет столкновений должен осуществляться обходом соответствующего пула (с обходом всех детектируемых объектов). Я же говорю, что ООП и паттерны не решают проблему, а только ее усложняют и запутывают. Способы решения проблемы модульности необходимо рассматривать на примере простой парадигмы, например, процедурной. Потому что более сложные парадигмы являются производными от простых.

Comment: Я читал и Фуллера, и много кого еще. Исходная проблема межмодульных зависимостей не решается, а только маскируется и обходится окольными путями.

Comment: Если вы все это читали и у вас все равно не получается - не знаю, что вам сказать. Могу анекдот рассказать про "Всю Одессу устраивает, а его не устраивает". Хотите? В ООП нет 100% гарантирующих решение практик как в математике - подставил числа и все посчиталось. Тем не менее, худо-бедно проблема уменьшения взаимозависимостей решается. В вашем примере проблема в том, что вы (намеренно или нет) постоянно добавляете зависимости в текстовое описание проблемы: "а я хочу это", "а еще вот это". Задайте себе вопрос иначе: "как решить проблему, не имея этого и этого?" Подумайте над ним хотя бы 5 минут

Comment: Давайте прекратим вести бессодержательное обсуждение темы, которая не является темой вопроса. ООП к моему вопросу относится чуть менее, чем никак.